# Remove items from my cart in php

Tags: php, shopping-cart, cart

I need some help here in removing items from my cart. I searched a lot of result but couldn't understand where to unset session and how to unset it. I tried using it but no result. Some thing I got, like I have to unset Session ID of the product that I want to remove from my cart. I learning php. so please can someone help me with details and solve this.

**my-cart.php**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">

            <?php
            $ucd=$dbobj->cart();
                    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($ucd)) : ?>
            <?php
            $arr=split(',', $_SESSION["usercart"]); //1&2,3&5
            $tot=sizeof($arr); //2
            $qty=0;

            for($i=0; $i<$tot; $i++)
            {       
                $ids=split('&', $arr[$i]);  //1 2   | 3 4
                if($row['productid']==$ids[0])
                $qty=$ids[1];
                        }
            ?>

            <tr>
                <td hidden="hidden"><?php echo $row['productid']; ?></td>
                <td><img src="<?php echo $row["product_image"]; ?>" width="200px" height="200px" /></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['product_name']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $qty; ?></td> 
                        <td><?php echo $row['product_price']; ?></td>
                <td><?php $totprice=$row['product_price']*$qty;
                         echo $totprice;
                $grandtot+=$totprice;
                  ?></td>  
                <td><a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" >REMOVE ITEM</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
```

Here is the function I created to add products in the cart.

**Cart function**

```
public function cart()
    {
        $arr=split(',', $_SESSION["usercart"]); //1&2,3&5
        $tot=sizeof($arr); //2
        $s='';
        for($i=0;$i<$tot;$i++)
        {
            $ids=split('&', $arr[$i]);  //1 2   | 3 4
            $s=$s.$ids[0].',';  //1,3,
        }
        $s=$s.'0';
        $this->com=mysql_query("select * from product where productid in($s)", $this->con);     //1,3,0
        return $this->com;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: use session_unset() or $_SESSION["usercart"]="";

Comment: how to use it in Remove item button? can you please explain it to me? thanks

Comment: This is not a coding service. Read php.net + coding tutorials and come back if youve got something that doesnt work

Comment: Fixed Code Titles, Grammar